# Customizing Jfreechart category item label

Tags: jfreechart

I want to show the category item label (x axis )as hyperlink.
options that i tried are,
1.When i try to set the text as html with link, it is not rendered as a link.
2.overriding the StandardCategoryURLGenerator's generateURL() to return URL. but couldnt see any difference in the label.

Comment: What is the context? Desktop application? Web Application?

Comment: Desktop application

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more context for your question. For example, edit the question to include the full code you're using at the moment and which changes you tried. Based on your code, more people will be able to support you.

Comment: In a desktop application, I'd have a [`ChartMouseListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20ChartMouseListener) invoke `Desktop.browse()`.

Comment: CustomCategoryURLGenerator generator = new CustomCategoryURLGenerator() {
            @Override
            public String generateURL(CategoryDataset dataset, int series, int category) {
                return "https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/CategoryItemLabelGenerator.html";
            }
        };
        renderer.setBaseItemURLGenerator(generator);

Comment: I expect the categoryLabel to appear as an URL and when clicked on link ,i shall be able to navigate to the page. Is my understanding about CustomCategoryURLGenerator 
 correct? However the above code doesnt make any difference. The tried to set on BarRenderer and CategoryItemRenderer.

Comment: AFAIK, a `CategoryURLGenerator` is meant to be used for HTML image map generation.